# Broadcasting audio to multiple listeners

Tags: windows, audio, streaming

I am GMing for a Table-top RPG game online and I would like to provide my players with music and ambient sounds to make the game more interesting.

Roll20, the software I am using does feature a way to stream audio, but this is only via Soundcloud which highly limits my ability to change the audio quickly and not require hours of preparation.

I would like to be able to stream audio from my computer to my 4 players.
The solution can stream 100% of the computer audio output as I will be using a separate laptop exclusively for the audio, no need to pick and chose which signal should be sent.

I am not a very proficient user so simple solutions are preferred.

Comment: Try using winamp with a shoutcast or icecast plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoLAN [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) can act as both a server and a client for media streaming, both audio and video.

Just open VLC on your host computer, select Media->Stream, point it to the source(s), step through the wizard.

[image]

It is Free & Cross platform.

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that there will usually be a delay between you playing and them hearing, even on a "live" stream on a local network.  Using multiple sets of software over a period of about 10 years I noticed that there was a consistent 12 to 13 second delay.  RealPlayer/RealServer, VLC, Wowza, etc. all exhibited this.

Comment: Almost all streaming software buffers a period of time so as to allow network path variations to be recovered from.