# Website to broadcast audio to multiple listeners

Tags: web-apps, audio

I'm facing the same trouble as the OP [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36010/broadcasting-audio-to-multiple-listeners), however, I need a website, not a program to be installed on my PC. I'm looking for a platform that allows me to upload my own audios and play more than just one audio at the same time.

I was using [Tabletop Audio](https://tabletopaudio.com/soundpad.html) until now, but it is limited to its own audios, so now I'm looking for a way to play my own audios as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Navidrome](https://www.navidrome.org/) to stream your music files (flac, mp3, etc.), and make it accessible to your network or on the internet.

It is opensource and runs on Windows, Linux, and MacOS. Your digitial files need to be tagged though e.g. Artist, Album, etc.

You can play the music via a web browser e.g. http://localhost:4533, or alternatively you can use one of the compatible Android or IOS Clients.

Anyone with access to the server can then also play your music independently on their own devices.

I have been using it for a while, and it is easy to setup and use.

There is a demo link on the [github](https://github.com/navidrome/navidrome/) page.

Edit:

[To add addtional solutions from comments]

- If you don't want to host, you can upload the music files to say a service like [MixCloud](https://www.mixcloud.com), after creating an account. You can then play directly via webrowser (laptop/computer or mobile phone) or via their mobile phone app. It allows you to create playlists of material available or uploaded to the site.
- Another similar solution is [iBroadcast](https://ibroadcast.com).

Comment: Unfortunately it's still a program. I don't have permission to install anything on this PC, so I need it to be entirely web-based.

Comment: If you are running it on a Windows PC, all you need to do is run an executable. No need to install anything - just unzip to a directory and run. Since you have a login to the PC, you should be able to do that? Your music files on the same PC? If not, get some VPS or web space and do same.

Comment: If you don't want to host, you can upload the music files to say a service like MixCloud.com, after creating an account. You can then play directly via webrowser (laptop/computer or mobile phone) or via their mobile phone app. It allows you to create playlists of material available or uploaded to the site.

Comment: No problem. Also check out https://ibroadcast.com/